# Accessing Remote Desktop on multiple windows machines behind NAT

Tags: windows, security, remote-desktop, nat, rdp

Our company has multiple Windows servers running behind a NAT firewall. We would like to provide Remote Desktop access to these machines to our users.

One of the solutions is by port forwarding. We can set up RDP to run on a specific port and forward that port at the from the firewall. However, this opens up a lot of ports at the firewall and we don't want to use this strategy.

I was thinking if there is a solution similar to ssh gateways. ([Is there a name based virtual host SSH reverse proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/34552/is-there-a-name-based-virtual-host-ssh-reverse-proxy))

Is there any other solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Remote Desktop Gateway server would do the job for you. From [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560672%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> Remote Desktop Gateway (RD Gateway), formerly Terminal Services
>   Gateway (TS Gateway), is a role service in the Remote Desktop Services
>   server role included with Windows Server® 2008 R2 that enables
>   authorized remote users to connect to resources on an internal
>   corporate or private network, from any Internet-connected device that
>   can run the Remote Desktop Connection (RDC) client. The network
>   resources can be Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host)
>   servers, RD Session Host servers running RemoteApp programs, or
>   computers and virtual desktops with Remote Desktop enabled. RD Gateway
>   uses the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) over HTTPS to establish a
>   secure, encrypted connection between remote users on the Internet and
>   internal network resources.

Answer (score 2):

There is also this solution [as posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25470588/195835)...

> Windows Vista onwards provides secure RDP connectivity over IPv6 without port forwarding configuration on NAT.
>
> This feature is called **Windows Internet Computer Names** (WICN) & it gives a unique name to your computer by which you can directly RDP to the machine.
>
> See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727045.aspx